# Extracting data from Investing.com to Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I am using google sheet function to extract a table from investing.com, the data I need is on daily basis, where there is a button in the page named "daily". However since the default setting of the page is "hourly", when I use "importhtml" in google sheet the data given is on an hourly basis. The url for both "daily" and "hourly" is exactly the same. How can I extract the "daily" data?

[image]

https://www.investing.com/equities/apple-computer-inc-technical

Comment: Can you show your mporthtml function that your pulling in? e.g. which index your choosing for "table" - I think I have an answer for you , but I cant compare results without knowing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is an interesting workaround that works - for whatever reason - the mobile version of their site defaults to daily instead of hourly - the table indices are slightly differently ordered.

**Original Function**

But for example for this table, which on the regular page (the one you listed) would be :

`=IMPORTHTML("https://www.investing.com/equities/apple-computer-inc-technical","table",5)`

[image]

**New Function**

And for the same table with the mobile site you get daily:

`=IMPORTHTML("https://m.investing.com/equities/apple-computer-inc-technical","table",0)`

[image]